# Remove JSON data pairs from nested structure

Tags: python, json, api

Relatively new here, and relatively new with Python, API, JSON etc..

If I have a JSON response from an API call that look like this:

```
{
    "data": {
        "type": "regulations",
        "id": "1234",
        "attributes": {
            "name": "My Own Regulations",
            "description": "",
            "created_at": "2021-10-20T15:27:57.834Z",
            "updated_at": "2021-10-20T15:27:57.834Z",
            "external_id": null,
            "source": null,
            "locked": false
        }
    }
}
```

And I am handling this in Python, how do I iterate the data to remove, say, "created_at" from the JSON?

Thanks! And sorry in advance if I am not posting this in the right way etc.

Comment: `del my_dict['data']['attributes']['created_at']`

Comment: thank you for your help!